# AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE for html, css, js. svg. ico, xml

Tags: .htaccess

**I want to send the following files compressed:**

- html (html5)
- css
- js
- svg
- ico
- xml (eg sitemap.xml)

**Is this the right code for that:**

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript image/svg+xm image/x-icon text/xml
```

**I would also like to know if I can and if there is any point to send the following as compressed? (need to know what to write as well :)**

- php
- pdf
- zip
- flw
- jpg
- png